# How add Second HDD and create new folders for sharing

Tags: server, permissions, mount, samba

I've recently installed Ubuntu Server v17.04 to my HP Proliant Gen 6 Microserver (N45l) on an internal USB stick.I am very new to Ubuntu but I thought I'd give it a try. I (think) I've added my 2tb HDD.

How can I ensure the secondary HDD is installed/mounted properly, and then create directories on it?

I have looked around at a few guides but they baffle me a bit. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I fail to see how this is a duplicate of either. The first uses a GUI to format a drive (where I am on server), and it no where explains "How can I ensure the secondary HDD is installed/mounted properly". Instead it shows how to format a HDD using a GUI. The second is nothing to do with what I asked and therefore cannot be a duplicate. It is useful though so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for available drives and list their mount point use:

```
lsblk
```

The `-f` flag will scan for file systems, UUIDs and labels (requires super-user privileges).

Comment: Thank you, this should sort out my issue. I knew about the `lsblk` but didn't realise the `-f` flag.